# Azure maps REST API link not working

Tags: azure, azure-maps

https://atlas.microsoft.com/search/address/json?subscription-key=[subscription-key]&api-version=1.0&query=15127
 NE 24th Street, Redmond, WA 98052

This link is not working. I added the subscription key but still getting this message 'Could not get any response'.

Comment: And so...?   What would you like us to do about it?

Comment: Is this the right link I'm using? or it is a issue from azure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

I am using this service from unsupported region. That is why azure map REST API link was not working.

Comment: You can mark this reply as the answer to help other to be clear for this issue and avoid it.

Answer (score 2):

I just tried the link and it worked for me. You sure you have the right subscription-key? (I don't see anything wrong the the url and the service is up as well)

https://atlas.microsoft.com/search/address/json?subscription-key={subscription_key}&api-version=1.0&query=15127%20NE%2024th%20Street,%20Redmond,%20WA%2098052

Also, What's the response status code that you get back?

Comment: I'm hitting the link from postman and I'm getting this : Could not get any response
There was an error connecting to https://atlas.microsoft.com/search/address/json?subscription-key=%7BqHPXXbqnSd0PyDXEzQLyGoAZ-BEwnvHhm3yOqMBUuVE%7D&api-version=1.0&query=15127%2520NE%252024th%2520Street,%2520Redmond,%2520WA%252098052.

Comment: Yeah definitely looks like an issue with the subscription key. You are getting a 401 unauthorized. I would go into azure portal and confirm that the key is correct/valid. { "statusCode": 401, "message": "Access denied due to invalid subscription key. Make sure to provide a valid key for an active subscription." }

Comment: I think I'm not hitting the link because if I am then postman should give me 401 unauthorised but in my case it is giving me the error connecting to this url